# Fitnesse Test, defining environment variable for path in content.txt

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, integration, fitnesse

Does any one have idea, what if i want to define path with some environment variable in fitnesse setup via content.txt.

At this moment we have content.txt checked in our repository containing the path variable of each and every developers environment. I want to resolve that problem by defining atleast a variable prefix with a standard path.

Current path definitions like below:

!path /home/xyz/workspace/blah/blah

Want to change it to something like

!path $workspace/blah/blah

I tried using !define workspace {this/is/my/path}

but it doesn't seems to be working and complains undefined variable workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `${myvariable}` to reference a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Mike has pointed out that the way you referring variable is wrong. Here are some more details for those who get confused between `${variable}` and `$slimSymbol` when first started using FitNesse.

`${variable}` is a concept on the Wiki page level . There are a few ways to define them:

1. using `!define` statement
2. properties in the `plugins.properties` file
3. using system variable passed when starting FitNesse Server
4. through url params

These variable will be translated at the time the page is visited. You can find some official documentation [here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.MarkupVariables)

`$slimSymbol` on the other hand is a "runtime variable" used in SLiM test system. They are defined by using `$slimSymbol=` symtax in the test case, and the value will only be available in the runtime. Documentation [here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables)